# PDF of a function of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have a function

$g(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2) = { {k_0 + k_1x_1 + k_2y_1 + k_3x_1^2 + k_4 y_1^2 + k_5 x_1 y_1} \over {k_0 + k_1x_2 + k_2y_2 + k_3x_2^2 + k_4 y_2^2 + k_5 x_2 y_2}}$

$k_0, k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4, k_5$ are random variables with specific $PDF$.

I am wondering how the $PDF$ of $g(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2)$ could be computed for a given set of value for $(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2)$

Comment: I wonder why the $\text{pdf}$ concept appears at the last line. It is also very unclear in your explanation what is known and what is not.

Comment: Because the constants $k_0, k_1$ are unknown and to be thought of as random variables. I thought I must actually be looking into the PDF of $g()$ and choose the value for $x_2,y_2$ such that it maximizes the chances of $g()$ is close to $1$. Please correct me if my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: By lack of understanding of your question, I can't further comment. Anyway, taking $(x_2,y_2)=(x_1,y_1)$ will probably ensure $g=1$ :-)

Comment: I updated the question. Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\text{cdf}$ of the random variable $G$ can be computed from the $\text{pdf}$ of the random variables $k_i$ and the parameters $x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2$, by the terrible integral

$$\text{cdf}_{G(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2)}=\mathbb P(G(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2)<g)=\\\iiiint\iiint_D 
\text{pdf}_{K_0}(k_0)\text{pdf}_{K_1}(k_1)\text{pdf}_{K_2}(k_2)\text{pdf}_{K_3}(k_3)\text{pdf}_{K_4}(k_4)\text{pdf}_{K_5}(k_5)\,dk_0\,dk_1\,dk_2\,dk_3\,dk_4\,dk_5\,$$

where the integration domain $D$ is defined by

$${ {k_0 + k_1x_1 + k_2y_1 + k_3x_1^2 + k_4 y_1^2 + k_5 x_1 y_1} \over {k_0 + k_1x_2 + k_2y_2 + k_3x_2^2 + k_4 y_2^2 + k_5 x_2 y_2}}<g$$ (this is a half-hyperspace).

To get the $\text{pdf}$, you differentiate on $g$.

Comment: If we know the numerical data for each of the $PDF_Ki$ , do you know any way, pointer to compute the $PDF$ of $G$ in numerical form?

Comment: From the given data points, you might construct interpolation curves, for instance piecewise polynomial, such as cubic splines, for each $k_i$. With a polynomial integrand and the linear contraint, I guess that an analytical solution is possible. But this seems to be hard work. The integrand will actually be a piecewise multivariate polynomial in hyperboxes, some of which the splitting hyperplane will clip.

Comment: If you simply take a piecewise constant model (i.e. a 6D histogram), the $\text{cdf}$ will result from the summation of the products of probabilities of the whole cells, and the clipped cells. As the plane moves, the intersected hypervolume will evolve following a degree $6$ polynomial, and the complete $\text{cdf}$ will be piecewise polynomial of that degree.